# Where does Lollipop stores notification policy?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, file-system

Unlike its predecessor Android versions which saves notification policy in the file `/data/system/notification_policy.xml` (the file which saves the package name of apps you've selected to stop giving notifications by unchecking "Show notifications" from **Settings → Apps →** your app name) Lollipop doesn't seem to follow that concept.

I have a Oneplus One running rooted CyanogenOS 12 (CM12). I also tested Paranoid ROM (AOSP) running Lollipop and the behavior remains same i.e. disregard for that file.

In the logcat's output the entries I see when I uncheck and later check "Shows notifications" for an app (e.g. AutomateIt) is:

```
[ 08-24 15:46:43.441   899: 1966 V/NotificationService ]
enabling notifications for AutomateIt.mainPackage

[ 08-24 15:47:01.361   899: 1966 V/NotificationService ]
disabling notifications for AutomateIt.mainPackage
```

Surprisingly, the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java) of Notification Manager Service doesn't seem to disregard the said file.

So, where does Lollipop keeps notification policies which are effectively executed by system?

**Edit**: Compared to Android Kitkat or below, how Lollipop uses that file? Can a user simply change the content in that file and expect the notification policy for an app to be changed after a reboot. The process is very simple in Jelly Bean though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/commit/4a900acdef4559f9f84ca7e2bce45485215fc130) notification policy settings were migrated from the separate `/data/system/notification_policy.xml` file to the generic AppOps subsystem. Now they are stored in `/data/system/appops.xml` together with other AppOps settings.

Comment: +1. Based on the answers [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120169/96277) it would seem that appops is not specific to CM ROMs which answers my earlier (now deleted) comment.